# Splitting a column using character delimiter

Tags: sql, sql-server, split, ssms

Can I have some help with this SQL and splitting a column string?

The output I got at the moment

```
ID_Reference | Balance
  203587         -902
  203948         -111
```

The output I need it:

```
ID_Reference | Balance
  203587         902
  203948         111
```

The code I am using is below:

```
select AccountReference,CurrentBalance from SB_RentAccountBalances_V where CurrentBalance like '-%'
```

Thanks,

Comment: I assume you are using SQL Server, so I added a tag.

Answer (score 4):

You would seem to want the `abs()` function:

```
select AccountReference, abs(CurrentBalance) as Balance
from SB_RentAccountBalances_V
where CurrentBalance < 0;
```

Admittedly, I'm assuming that a column called `CurrentBalance` is actually a number and not a string.

If it is a string, then you can remove the leading `-`.  In SQL Server, you would use:

```
select AccountReference, stuff(CurrentBalance, 1, 1, '') as Balance
from SB_RentAccountBalances_V
where CurrentBalance like '-%';
```

Comment: To add, if it's actually a string, convert it to a numeric data type. @sqldan

Answer (score 0):

I hope you want this out put

```
select AccountReference,abs(CurrentBalance) CurrentBalance from 
SB_RentAccountBalances_V where CurrentBalance like '-%'
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to replace - with blank for the desired output. Try the below code

```
select AccountReference,
       replace(CurrentBalance,'-','') as 'CurrentBalance'
from SB_RentAccountBalances_V where CurrentBalance like '-%'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT ID_Reference,
       SUBSTRING(Balance,CHARINDEX('-',Balance)+1,Len(Balance))AS Balance 
 FROM SB_RentAccountBalances_V
 WHERE CHARINDEX('-',Balance)>0
```

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which may provide some immediate help.  A proper explanation [would greatly improve](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) its educational value by showing *why* this is a good solution to the problem, and would make it more useful to future readers with similar, but not identical, questions.  Please [edit] your answer to add explanation, and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.